# How many computers can use a single Windows 7 license key?

Tags: windows-7, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One License and multiple PCs, how does it work?](https://superuser.com/questions/74835/one-license-and-multiple-pcs-how-does-it-work)

I know for previous versions of Windows, you were allowed to install the same key onto 3 different computers. Is this the same with Windows 7?

Comment: Isn't it kind of the same question?
http://superuser.com/questions/74835/one-license-and-multiple-pcs-how-does-it-work

Comment: You might be thinking of the Family Pack for Vista and Windows 7. You could install it on up to three computers with these editions. Unfortunately, I believe both have been discontinued, Windows 7 just recently.

Answer (score 3):

Windows OEM - One machine and dies with that machine.
Windows Upgrade - Upgrades a single copy of Windows to the latest version.
Windows Fully packaged Product - Only one machine, but can be moved to another machine (can only be installed at one place at any one time).
Windows 7 Family Pack - 3 licences for different computers at any one time.

Windows Activation is designed to stop pirates from installing on hundreds of computers, if you just install it on a couple of machines, it will work - and if you hit the limit, then ring them up, they usually authorise it **HOWEVER** it doesn't mean it is legal to break the limits just because it works.

Comment: Actually, you can move an OEM licence too. Just don’t resell it.

Comment: @kinokijuf No, you can't!

Comment: I’ve done it many times. It successfully activates and validates as lpng as you’re not using it on more than one PC at once.

Comment: @kinokijuf - you are talking about Fully Packaged Product where you are allowed to use it on more than one PC.... OEM is only allowed on one machine and the license dies with the machine - just because it works, doesn't mean that you are legally allowed to.

Comment: No, with FPP you can still only use it on one computer at a time. The activation works the same for FPP and OEM in fact.

Comment: @kinokijuf I mean that FPP allows you to uninstall and re use as many times as you like... OEM is one and only one machine - even if you uninstall it.... If it is what you think, what are the differences between FPP and OEM? Why would anyone purchase FPP when OEM is much cheaper?

Comment: @kinokijuf The [OEM licence](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx) specifies that it is linked to the hardware. When discussing licences, it is important to remember what you are allowed to do legally may be different from what you are able to do technically (i.e. the software may not necessarily be stopping you, but you would be violating the licence terms). Specifically, *The software license is permanently assigned to the computer with which the software is distributed. That computer is the “licensed computer.”*.

Comment: @kinokijuf Compare to the full retail version, which does state that it is 'permanently assigned'. Also, *You may use the software on up to two processors on the licensed computer at one time. Unless otherwise provided in these license terms, you may not use the software on any other computer.*. Note that the OEM licence does not provide provisions for transferring to another computer (except with the *licensed computer* to a third party), while the retail licence explicitly allows you to *transfer the software and install it on another computer for your use*.

Comment: @kinokijuf Since there is no provision for transferring it to another computer in the OEM licence, then the earlier clause holds true and *you may not use the software on any other computer*.

Comment: (correction of a typo, in the first sentence of my second comment I meant the full retail version *doesn't* state that it is 'permanently assigned')

Comment: IANAL. I am only stating how it is from technical side.

Comment: I lost the notion of what constitutes a “single computer” when confronted with a pile of old components (half of them broken) and a Windows licence.

Comment: @kinokijuf again, technically and legally are very different - if you upgrade/repair, you will be allowed to reinstall without issue... as long as you are within "the spirit" of the license, nothing bad will happen. If you start loading the same key on many machines, you will start having a problem

Answer (score 2):

There has never been a general "3 computers per license" rule for Windows.  Consumer licenses are one computer to one license (at a time).  If the license is non-OEM, it's transferable to a new system if it's removed from the old system.

So, to answer your question, Windows 7 operates in the same fashion: one system per consumer license.

Comment: Interestingly, you can run 4 virtual instances on the same computer with one (Ultimate) license, http://serverfault.com/questions/53409.

Comment: Virtual machines are not that simple. It might be that windows 7 recognizes the motherboard as being the same, even though it's in a VM, and thus it still counts as the same computer.

Comment: Or, I could have clicked your link and read the post =P. Seems it's actually designed to be able to run 4 VMs. Wonder if they actually count... :-)

Comment: By definition, a VM CANNOT know what sort of machine it's running on. It may be possible to detect it IS in a VM, or at least make a good guess.