# The same Windows 7 license on multiple Computers

Tags: windows-7, license, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One License and multiple PCs, how does it work?](https://superuser.com/questions/74835/one-license-and-multiple-pcs-how-does-it-work)

I have a student license for Windows 7, which I run on my desktop.

I also want to also install it on my laptop.  Can I use the same serial number, or will I run into problems?

Comment: duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/74835/one-license-and-multiple-pcs-how-does-it-work ... http://superuser.com/questions/83293/how-many-computers-can-use-a-single-windows-7-license-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can not do that according to the license agreement, if you run it on two computers with the same serial number, one of your computer will be required to enter a valid serial number, and it can not be activated successfully.

Comment: This is not correct; some types of serial number (MSDN, etc) permit multiple activations, not only in the license but also in the activation process. Past that limit, you have to phone it in. MSDN is/was 10 unique achine activations per serial, for example.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that with Windows, you may be confused due to the Office licensing. For student editions Microsoft allow you to install it onto 2 machines, a desktop and a laptop, presumably so that you can take notes in lectures and write essays, finalise work etc on a main desktop pc. Unfortunately this is **not** the case with Windows.
There was a family pack edition of Windows 7 released from launch to December 4th 2009, this allowed you to activate the license on 3 machines but unfortunately has been discontinued by Microsoft.